# Neo4j cypher optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

From a set of stuff to like, I want to find out how many of a set of users like what stuff.

Indexes exist on the User label for the userId property, as well as for the StuffToLike label and its stuffId property.

Both {users} and {stuff} parameters will receive arrays with ids.
For this phase, the {users} array will hold in between 100 to 1,000,000 strings, while the {stuff} array will have 100 strings in it.

This is the most simplified and fastest solution with the least db hits I have up until this point.

```
  MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.userId IN {users}
  MATCH (n:StuffToLike) WHERE n.stuffId IN {stuff}
  OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[l:LIKES]-(u)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[d:DISLIKES]-(u)
  RETURN {
      stuffId: n.stuffId,
      name: n.name,
      likes: count(l),
      dislikes: count(d)
  } AS stuff
```

I don't expect real-time usability for this amount of data (yet), but it'd be great if I can run this in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.userId IN {users} WITH collect(u) as users
MATCH (n:StuffToLike) WHERE n.stuffId IN {stuff}
RETURN {
      stuffId: n.stuffId,
      name: n.name,
      likes: size([u in users WHERE (n)<-[:LIKES]-(u)]),
      dislikes: size([u in users WHERE (n)<-[:DISLIKES]-(u)])
  } AS stuff
```

Also how fast is this:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.userId IN {users} WITH collect(u) as users
MATCH (n:StuffToLike) WHERE n.stuffId IN {stuff}
RETURN {
      stuffId: n.stuffId,
      name: n.name,
      likes: size((n)<-[:LIKES]-()),
      dislikes: size((n)<-[:DISLIKES]-())
  } AS stuff
```

Comment: Thank you. The db hits are significantly reduced and it's somewhat faster. I'll run it against a larger set when the load on the server is lower. The overall popularity of the StuffToLike as shown in your second query is fairly fast. It really slows down when only looking at the popularity from within that ever changing set of users.